# Javascript Salute Show

Tags: javascript, date, hour

Good morning.

Please, i want to show a salute-message depending on hours.. Tried this auto-initializing function, it works,  but  independs what time is it, he display: "Good Night". What i'm doing wrong?? Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
(function(){

    function saluteText() {

        var d = new Date();
        var time = d.getHours();
        var divInnerHTML = document.querySelector('.name');

        if (time < 12) {
            function addInnerHTML() {
                divInnerHTML.innerHTML = 'Good morning!';
            }
        }
        else if (time >=12 && time <18) {
            function addInnerHTML() {
                divInnerHTML.innerHTML = 'Good evening!';
            }
        }
        else if (time >= 18 && time < 24) {
            function addInnerHTML() {
                divInnerHTML.innerHTML = 'Good night!';
            }
        }

        addInnerHTML();
    }
    saluteText()
})();
```

Comment: Why do you have those `addInnerHTML()` functions? Why not just set the innerHTML directly in each if/else case? If you want to conditionally define a function you need to declare `var addInnerHTML;` before the if/else block and then set `addInnerHTML = function() { ...}` within the if/else.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a problem of defining your functions.

When you define a function in javascript, it is placed on top of the scope.

You define the function three times and the last one is only shown. Even if you place the declaration between If statements all three will be created.

You can try this out by removing the last function and you will see that the code says 'Good evening'.

In this case the solution to your problem would be this approach:

```
function addInnerHTML(message) {
    divInnerHTML.innerHTML = message;
}

if (time < 12) {

   addInnerHTML('Good morning!');
}
else if (time >=12 && time <18) {

    addInnerHTML('Good evening!');
}
else if (time >= 18 && time < 24) {

    addInnerHTML('Good night!');
}
```

Comment: *"When you define a function in javascript, it is placed on top of the call stack."* - The call stack? That's not right. Also, your solution now defines the `addInnerHTML()` function *four* times.

Comment: You are correct i submitted this answer a bit to fast. As sumeet states that functions are hoisted I confused these two. When I get the chance I will adjust this answer thanks.